# Why did the Empire choose to build the second Death Star near Endor?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, endor

I was wondering why the Empire chose to build the second Death Star in orbit around the Forest Moon of Endor?

I guess that having locals who aren't capable of space flight is handy, but aren't there *fully* uninhabited planets hidden away in the Outer Rim, that would be just as defensible, and less well-known to the rest of the galaxy?

Apparently Endor is known for producing [Ewok Jerky](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewok_Jerky), so you'd imagine that many people would want more, take a trip, and notice the Death Star being built there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply put, the Endor system was simultaneously incredibly remote (dramatically lowering the chances of anyone stumbling onto the project by accident) and highly accessible *if you knew the secret navigational codes that were required to access the "[Sanctuary Pipeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sanctuary_Pipeline)"*, a lengthy hyperspace route that led directly from Sullust to Endor.

> Red lines appeared on the spiral arms—the great trade routes that connected the galaxy’s star systems. Ackbar gestured, and a red dot sprang into existence in a location Leia recognized: Sullust, the homeworld of Nien Nunb. Then another dot appeared, on the edge of the galaxy. A dotted blue line stretched between them.
>
> “The Empire has used S-thread boosters to create and maintain a secret
>   hyperspace route running from Sullust all the way to the galactic
>   edge,” Ackbar said. “It’s called the Sanctuary Pipeline and is one of
>   the Empire’s most important military secrets. Fortunately, our agents
>   discovered the navigational data that will allow us to use it, too.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Moving Target](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_Target:_A_Princess_Leia_Adventure)</sup></sub>

As to why Endor was chosen (over, say, another more accessible but still unexplored planet), that was down to the Emperor himself.

> The shield generator could have been built in any of thousands of desolate, lifeless planetary systems. **But the Emperor himself picked this spot from several suggested by Imperial engineers.**
>   The engineers liked the idea of burning up the moon’s resources to fuel the shield.
>   And **the Emperor liked the idea of crushing something beautiful.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Comment: Surely the "Sanctuary Pipeline" is not the *only* hyperspace route to Endor, merely the best one directly from Sullust. Otherwise how would "Ewok Jerky" be transported offworld?

Comment: @Null - The "Absolutely Everything" guide doesn't *specifically* say that Endor is the only place you can get Ewoks from, just that they're hunted for food.

Comment: [Ewok jerky](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewok_Jerky) was known during the time of the Clone Wars (i.e. before the Empire charted the Sanctuary Pipeline). Since Ewoks are native to Endor someone must have been aware of an alternate route to Endor, even if only to transport a bunch of Ewoks offworld in order to hunt them for food elsewhere.

Comment: @Null - All of the references I've read indicate that Endor is *remote* rather than inaccessible. Presumably that goes for double when Ewok meat smugglers are insta-killed as soon as they drop out of hyperspace into the middle of the Empire's most heavily guarded project

Comment: Right, Endor should be accessible even if you don't know about the Sanctuary Pipeline since that's how people got to Endor before the Empire took over. And if that's the case then anyone -- rebels, Ewok hunters, etc. -- would know how to get to Endor. Yes, the Empire can kill anyone who enters the system but people are going to start to notice that no one ever comes back after traveling to the Endor system. That just brings us back to the original question: why didn't the Empire use a remote system that also wouldn't attract hunters of the native life?

Comment: For the record, I've upvoted this for the second quote (about the Emperor liking the idea of crushing something beautiful). I think the part about the Sanctuary Pipeline doesn't really explain it.

Comment: @Null - you have to remember that this is a case of tail-wag-dog. Ewok Jerky was an easter egg joke in one of the clone wars episodes that the writers of the AA factbook decided to canonise.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm sadly all too aware that The Clone Wars cartoons and Disney have been wreaking havoc on the Star Wars canon.

Comment: @Null - Luckily we can all now time-travel back into the distant past to fix these canon errors.

Comment: @Null Just because it's technically *accessible* doesn't meant that anyone will go there. Endor is remote, meaning that there's not much near it worth visiting and so people are less likely to stumble across it. Outside of the Death Star it's not clear there is anything there that anyone would bother to get, so why would anyone bother to go there? (retcons of Ewoks-as-food obviously damages this, but can't be factors in the original decisions to locate the base there because that information wasn't true at that time those decisions were made).

Comment: (continued) And if you subscribe, as I do, to the idea that building a Death Star at all (let alone a second one!) indicates that the Emperor has the resources and clout to do whatever he wants, the question becomes "Why not Endor?".  Accessibility is necessary to get materials and staff to the construction site, and the Ewoks offer a pretty paltry resistance on their own. The Empire was strong, and its fall was the result of narrow miracles much moreso than it being unable to resist threats.

Comment: This answer contradicts itself.  "The Empire has used S-thread boosters to create and maintain a secret hyperspace route running from Sullust all the way to the galactic edge,”  If that's the case, they could have run it to anywhere.  They picked Endor first, then ran the line.

Comment: I wonder if the Emperor finds the Ewoks beautiful, or just the planet... Either way, great quotes @Valorum

Comment: @Longshanks - I think we can assume that the Emperor is a secret 'furry'

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Valourm's answer, The Emperor also knew about the Rebel fleet massing near Sullust.  Remember that the entire thing was a trap, and he was creating the best, most irresistible bait for it he that he could.  Including the possibility of killing both him AND Vader, in a single stroke.  The shuttle and the codes being stolen were all part of his scheme to crush the Rebellion in one, swift stroke.

Comment: Yeah, but part of his plan involved waiting until the Death Star's superlaser was operational and making the rebels think it *wasn't* operational. It took years to get the superlaser operational, and the Empire would have needed to keep secret the location (and *existence*) of the Death Star until that time.

Comment: Yeah. Makes more sense to say "it was repurposed as a trap", than to say "it was built as a trap". Actually it must have started after starting the first death star, latest after it exploded + some months. But it must have been in the making a LONG time.

Comment: Don't forget the upshot of [killing Bothans](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2004/08/25/this-is-an-allegory)

Comment: Who's Valourm...?